# namespace std has no member std::invoke_result_t

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang, std, c++17

I recently switched to VS Code from MSVS due to personal reasons, and my compiler is the latest Clang now.

I had some troubles (for example, I can't write `typename O = ...`, now I have to write `typename O = typename ...`), but all of them are small and easy to fix. Except one.

I don't know the reason, but compiler can't find `std::invoke_result_t` and `std::invoke_result<>::type`. It's disgusting a lot, especially because IntelliSense finds it easy.

Here's error log:

```
{"Workspace" directory}/Untitled-1.cpp:5:54: error: no template named 'invoke_result_t' in namespace 'std'; did you mean '_Invoke_result_t'?
template<typename I, typename FTy, typename O = std::invoke_result_t<std::function<FTy>, I>>
                                                ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                     _Invoke_result_t
{MSVS Installation directory}\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\include\type_traits:1832:2: note: '_Invoke_result_t' declared here
        using _Invoke_result_t = typename _Invoke_traits<void, _Callable, _Args...>::type;
        ^
1 error generated.
```

If I use offered `std::_Invoke_result_t` instead of normal one, everything compiles and works as it should.

Also, every time I compile my code, that contains `std::cout`, compiler write that some locally defined symbols (_CxxThrowException and _std_terminate, to be honest) were imported to functions from .

Is there any way to fix all these troubles? Which of them are bugs and which are features? I heard, VS C++ libraries don't accomplish to ISO standard, does it may be reason of my troubles?

Comment: Show Code, get help.

Comment: According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance), it's available in VS 2017.3.

Comment: std::invoke_result is AFAIK [not yet implemented in clang](http://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html). Issue [2087](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2807).

Comment: What's your code? Also, did you enabled the c++17 flag for clang?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot That's an `O` not a `0` ;)

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot -- in the question, it's the **letter** O, not the **number** 0. Look carefully... <g>

Comment: @chris Yes, it is. I used this thing a lot while MSVS was good enough for me. But after switch it stopped working.

Comment: You need to tell Clang that you want C++17 mode; pass `-std=c++17` or `-std=c++1z` on the command line.

Comment: @Jaa-c bad news. Do u know, how rarely clang updates?

Comment: @Casey yes, I did. Other c++17 features, provided by MSVS compile as well.

Comment: @Siborgium: Quite often. Use `std::result_of_t` in the meantime, the fix should be easy.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot  For example, this variant:
```
#include&amp;lt;iostream&amp;gt;
#include&amp;lt;type_traits&amp;gt;
#include&amp;lt;functional&amp;gt;

template &amp;lt;typename I, typename FTy, typename O = typename std::invoke_result_t&amp;lt;std::function&amp;lt;FTy&amp;gt;, I&amp;gt;&amp;gt;
const O apply(I i, std::function&amp;lt;FTy&amp;gt; f) {
    return f(i) ;} 

int main() {
    std::function &amp;lt;int(int)&amp;gt; f = [] (int x) { return x * x; } ;
    return apply(5, f) ;
} 
```

EDIT: posted it using mobile app, for some reasons markup broke. Sorry.

Comment: _code don't matter_ help either

Comment: @AndyG it's not Visual Studio.

Comment: Show your command line. Clang's default is still C++98, so you have to do something special to get C++03, C++11, C++14, C++17 or C++20 (and friends). As I understand it Clang 6 uses C++14 by default. Also see [Issue 35853, Clang 4.0 still uses C++98 by default](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35853).

Comment: @jww {path to clang binaries}clang.exe file.cpp -std=c++17 -o app.exe

Comment: I ended up here for compiling `autodiff/autodiff`, it saved me trying many compiler options `-pedantic` and `-std`

Answer (score 4):

`std::invoke_result` is part of C++17, please ensure that the compiler has the `-std=c++17` option.

Also,

```
#include <type_traits>
```

If you are using clang or a older version of c++ consider using `std::result_of`